# Displaying array values in a textfield

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array under another array and I want the value of the inner array and display them in UITextfield (eg : xyz,ABC,123) in iOS swift

```
let memberDetail = tobeReceivedArray[indexPath.row]["groupMembersVO"] 
self.memberArray = memberDetail as! [AnyObject] 
let amount = (tobeReceivedArray[indexPath.row]["totalPay"] as! Int) as NSNumber 
let date = tobeReceivedArray[indexPath.row]["uploadOn"] as! String 
let name = memberArray[indexPath.row]["name"] as! String 
cell.amountLable.text = amount.stringValue cell.timeLable.text = date 
cell.nameLable.text = name
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe we can look at it and tell you why it's not working.

Comment: Currently what are you getting ?

Comment: i do get values in the array.. i want to parse those values in textfield like name = xyz,abc,123

Comment: let memberDetail = tobeReceivedArray[indexPath.row]["groupMembersVO"]
            self.memberArray = memberDetail as! [AnyObject]
            
            let amount = (tobeReceivedArray[indexPath.row]["totalPay"] as! Int) as NSNumber
            let date = tobeReceivedArray[indexPath.row]["uploadOn"] as! String
            let name = memberArray[indexPath.row]["name"] as! String
 
            cell.amountLable.text = amount.stringValue
            cell.timeLable.text = date
            cell.nameLable.text = name

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use flat map for better understanding you can follow this link:
http://sketchytech.blogspot.in/2015/06/swift-what-do-map-and-flatmap-really-do.html